# How to set exact position of external monitor in XFCE?

Tags: xfce, multiple-monitors

There are few basic options to set up and external monitor in XFCE including "expand to right/left" but that's not enough I want to set position exactly because my monitors have different size.

How do I do that, every other system/DE I used had advanced drag&drop monitor position setting.

Comment: There's a program called `arandr`, which pretty much does what you ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a program called *ARandR*. It is basically the perfect program for your needs.

Description:

```
ARandR is a visual front end for XRandR 1.2/1.3 (per display options), which
provides full control over positioning, saving and loading to/from shell
scripts and easy integration with other applications.
```

If not already done, you can install ARandR via the Software Center or `sudo apt-get install arandr`.